# Python a comparison of the distributions?

Tags: python, packing

Does anyone have/know of a list that compares all the python distributions with their packages?

I have been looking for a kind of one shot installation method for locked down networks, where  I don't want to call the administrator every month to install Numpy, then matplotlib, etc...

I know of SCIPY, WinPython, and a few others but I haven't found a detailed comparison of each version/distributions?

Any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer to your actual question, but the best distribution for my money is Continuum's Anaconda- comes with numpy, matplotlib, ipython (including the QtConsole), and can be installed without admin privileges.

Comment: Also, I think this question is worth keeping open. If there *is* a page that gives a rundown of these distributions, it would be very useful. It's not subjective, it's asking where to find this information.

Comment: Thanks Marius I will definitely try that. It would be a great help if I could get away with all the basics.

I might also think about starting a WIKI comparison page